# Is there a method of counting an attribute that is in a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql

I need have created a select statement to list out all the customers that have been to multiple merchants below.

I want to create another statement to display how many of those customers have been to each merchant.

What is the optimal method of approaching this problem?

Lists out all customers that have been to multiple merchants.

```
WITH valentinesDayMerchant AS (
SELECT m.MerchantId, m.MerchantGroupId, m.WebsiteName 
FROM Merchant m 
INNER JOIN OpeningHours oh ON m.MerchantId = oh.MerchantId AND oh.DayOfWeek = 'TUE'
LEFT JOIN devices.DeviceConnectionState AS dcs ON dcs.MerchantId = oh.MerchantId
WHERE MerchantStatus = '-' AND (m.PrinterType IN ('V','O') OR dcs.State = 1 OR dcs.StateTransitionDateTime > '2023-01-23') 
)

SELECT DISTINCT ul.UserLoginId, ul.FullName, ul.EmailAddress, ul.Mobile
FROM dbo.UserLogin AS ul
INNER JOIN dbo.Patron AS p ON p.UserLoginId = ul.UserLoginId
INNER JOIN valentinesDayMerchant AS m ON (m.MerchantId = ul.ReferringMerchantId OR m.MerchantId IN (SELECT pml.MerchantId FROM dbo.PatronMerchantLink AS pml WHERE pml.PatronId = p.PatronId AND ISNULL(pml.IsBanned, 0) = 0))
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT mg.MerchantGroupId, mg.MerchantGroupName, groupHost.HostName [GroupHostName]
    FROM dbo.MerchantGroup AS mg
    INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant AS parent ON parent.MerchantId = mg.ParentMerchantId
    INNER JOIN dbo.HttpHostName AS groupHost ON groupHost.MerchantID = parent.MerchantId AND groupHost.Priority = 0
    ) mGroup ON mGroup.MerchantGroupId = m.MerchantGroupId 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT po.PatronId, MAX(po.OrderDateTime) [LastOrder]
    FROM dbo.PatronsOrder AS po
    GROUP BY po.PatronId
) orders ON orders.PatronId = p.PatronId
INNER JOIN dbo.HttpHostName AS hhn ON hhn.MerchantID = m.MerchantId AND hhn.Priority = 1
WHERE ul.UserLoginId NOT IN (1,2,100,372) AND ul.UserStatus <> 'D' AND (
    ISNULL(orders.LastOrder, '2000-01-01') > '2020-01-01' OR ul.RegistrationDate > '2022-01-01'
    )
GROUP BY ul.UserLoginId, ul.FullName, ul.EmailAddress, ul.Mobile
HAVING COUNT(m.MerchantId) > 1
```

Methods I have tried include adding the merchant name to a group by and displaying the count of the customers, however this does not work as I cannot have anything related to the Merchant in the GROUP BY, or I wouldn't be able to use HAVING clause to identify the customers that have been to multiple merchants. I have also tried selecting all the merchants and counting the distinct customers which doesn't work as it takes into account all the customers, not specifically the customers that have been to multiple merchants only.

Comment: I do not really understand the schema of your tables. Can you share some information about your tables and your goals?

Comment: Can I send pictures here?

Comment: You can attach pictures to your question, but it would be great if you could run `show create table <yourtablename;` in MySQL and paste the result as text into your question, it would allow us to copy-paste your column names rather than typing them by hand.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and then [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75431042/edit). You have tagged your question with `mysql` but it definitely looks like SQL Server, to me. Try to make clearer what you are trying to achieve. Is it a list of `valentinesDayMerchant` with their respective counts of customers, who are also linked to another `valentinesDayMerchant`?